# DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog do not use black overlay

Tags: android, kotlin, datepickerdialog

I am currently using **Android Studio Flamingo** version **2022.2.1 Patch 2**.

And from the tutorials I find on the internet, my dialog box opens but the background is not darkened, it stays white, how to solve it?

Follow my codes:

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
DatePickerDialog(this, this, 2023, 8, 30).show()
```

**themes.xml** (I believe there may be something theme related):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.TestComponents" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>
 
    <style name="Theme.TestComponents" parent="Base.Theme.TestComponents" />
 
</resources>
```

[image]

As seen in the image above, the screen underneath does not assume a darkened tone, how to solve it?